# When does server receives http request body?

Tags: http

Say my client is posting a http request, of which the body is 1 TB.
The first time when my server's http handler get invoked, how much of the request boday has been in my server's tcp socket receive-q?

Edited:
Actaully what I want to know is related to the details of http.
Say the size of the whole http request is very large (big size of headers, and big size of body):

1. Basically, I can use one TCP request to send the whole http request(the size of which is very big). I can also split the big http request into several smaller slices and send them with several TCP requests. Which way does http protocol implement?
2. When can we think that the http server can start to work from the point of view of http protocol?

For example:
All the path in the URL (the part after the host:port in the URL) has been available in the server's memory? Or,
All the http headers have been available in the server's memory? Or,
All the request body has been available in the server's memory?

Comment: Impossible to answer, since it entirely depends on the client, and the TCP protocol (or whatever) used to transmit the data. If the server reacts fast, it is very possible for none of the request body to have arrived yet. If the HTTP headers are large, the headers may even arrive piecemeal, however, the "http handler" is normally not invoked until the entire headers has been received, but it depends on the framework in question.

Comment: Depends on language/framework

Comment: Especially if the client is HTTP/1.1 (which nearly all are nowadays) and uses 100-continue (which those sending large request bodies probably should). Also, TCP is a stream protocol and does not preserve 'requests'; even if the sender uses one send() call the data may be delivered to the receiver as multiple recv() calls -- and _large_ data almost always is -- and even if the sender uses multiple send() calls (without PSH or an application response) the data may be delivered to a single recv(). See any decent textbook, like Stevens.